# Glyphicon icon change on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the glyphicon icon on click. Here is my html

```
<div id="icon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</div>
```

AND JS is

```
$('.glyphicon').click(function(){
$(this).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star');
});
```

please help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you wrapped the code in DOM ready event?

Comment: yes I wrapped the code in DOM ready event.

Answer (score 2):

Try using toggleClass();

```
$('.glyphicon').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star');
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/gtkc0s51/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried this locally using sublime text it's working but I am building an application in meteor using cloud 9  work space. I tried to do the same in the work space but it's not working, I don't know why. I am trying this from past 3 days.

Comment: have you consulted the console, of the page from cloud9?,is the jquery library added to the page?

Comment: yes it is added.<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: and the console, have you looked at it?

Comment: yup. It doesn't show any error. But the on click functionality is not working.

Comment: there, you have your answer, use event delegation if you dynamically add that icon

Comment: Thanks for the help.